# "A file or folder with the name 'bluhbluh.cs' already exists" although it doesn't

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Every time I try to create a new file - no matter what type - Visual Studio returns to me a message box that says that the file already exists when it doesn't. Some notes and what I've tried:

- Restarting my PC
- Restarting Visual Studio
- Repairing Visual Studio
- Delete the `ComponentModelCahce` folder under `/Appdata/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio/15.0_d0dd68d28`
- Trying to open a new file in a new/old project without git does work
- Used the `Show All` button to see if a file with that name does exists
- Use absurd names

This is being affected only in git projects, and I use:
Visual Assist, Resharper, OzCode, some addons, clearcase and easy git.

Comment: Maybe the file is in the folder, but not added to the project?

Comment: It's not - however I can create the file in the folder itself, but I can't include it to my project (via `Add existing item` or `Show All Files` -> `Include in Project`)

Comment: You could try to add it via source-control. Did you try that?

Comment: I did - but I found the problem, I would answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - 
The problem was with the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools` dlls - I had to copy them and probably something there was corrupted - copying new ones from another PC has solved the problem.